# read CID of SD card with SD.h library

Tags: esp8266, library, sd

I would like to be able to read the serial numbers of SD cards using the SD.h library. Only reading the values is enough, I am not looking to modify the CID.
This should be possible but I do not have the programming skills to get it running.

I am using an esp8266 and already have the SD card running and working correctly. Only the chipselect needed to be modified for the SD library to work.

So far I have found this in Sd2Card.h

```
      /**
   * Read a cards CID register. The CID contains card identification
   * information such as Manufacturer ID, Product name, Product serial
   * number and Manufacturing date. */
  uint8_t readCID(cid_t* cid) {
    return readRegister(CMD10, cid);
  }
  /**
```

And in Sd2Card.cpp there is this:

```
/** read CID or CSR register */
uint8_t Sd2Card::readRegister(uint8_t cmd, void* buf) {
  uint8_t* dst = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(buf);
  if (cardCommand(cmd, 0)) {
    error(SD_CARD_ERROR_READ_REG);
    goto fail;
  }
  if (!waitStartBlock()) goto fail;
  // transfer data
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) dst[i] = spiRec();
  spiRec();  // get first crc byte
  spiRec();  // get second crc byte
  chipSelectHigh();
  return true;

 fail:
  chipSelectHigh();
  return false;
}
```

So it seems that the underlying code has been prepared in the library already, my question is how would I include it into a sketch like CardInfo.ino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is visible from within your sketch. You just need to first create a `cid_t` struct like this in your sketch:

```
cid_t cid;  // at the top with the other globals
```

Then call `readCID()` anywhere in `setup()` after the card has been initialized.

```
card.readCID(&cid);
Serial.print("Serial number: "); Serial.println(cid.psn); // psn is the serial number field of the struct
```

Check out `SdInfo.h` for the other struct members.

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me and the explanation easy to follow. I tried additional information and can also read it. The SdInfo sketch is much better but it wouldn't run on my hardware, but I can see now how to use it as an example. Thanks again.